# "Requested resource not available" error upon accessing new apache-bloodhound installation

Tags: tomcat, wsgi, apache-bloodhound

I have installed apache-bloodhound on an Ubuntu-12.04 server using the the instructions at this location:

https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall

I can access the site using the tracd function under the heading "Testing the Server" and all appears to be well.

I created the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/bloodhound  as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   WSGIDaemonProcess bloodhound_tracker user=alex python-path=/usr/share/bloodhound/lib/python2.7/site-packages
   WSGIScriptAlias /bloodhound /usr/share/bloodhound/site/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
   <Directory /usr/share/bloodhound/site/cgi-bin>
     WSGIProcessGroup bloodhound_tracker
     WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
   <LocationMatch "/usr/share/bloodhound/[^/]+/login">
     AuthType Digest
     AuthName "bloodhound"
     AuthDigestDomain /bloodhound
     AuthUserFile /usr/share/bloodhound/environments/main/bloodhound.htdigest
     Require valid-user
   </LocationMatch>
 </VirtualHost>
```

But when I attempt to access the site, I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /bloodhound
type Status report
message /bloodhound
description The requested resource (/bloodhound) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
```

I am not familiar with WSGI,  but have delved into the documentation and not found anything obvious with this file. I do restart apache upon changing this file and have restarted the server also without success.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, the URL you are using is actually being routed through to a Java application and not mod_wsgi. So that VirtualHost is likely not enabled, or you haven't enabled name based virtual hosts for that port and is falling back to the first VirtualHost in the configuration which is proxying through to the Java application.